# Why .text only works inside onCreate ? At least at my code :

Tags: android, kotlin

I am learning android studio and I can't find out why it happens, I would appreciate if someone could explain me this:

When I place xxxxanything.text after the onCreate I get the error " expected member declaration" but it works inside the onCreate metod.Why does it happen ?

I saw activity life cycle some times but im still in doubt about where to put things, like onclick listener.

I were wondering at several guides already and I am working on udacity at moment, having a hard time to understand recyclerview and I also trying to develop good programing practices.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Works like this

```
package app.helloworld.dashimir.com.diceroller

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val rollButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.roll_button)
        rollButton.text = "Let's Roll"
    }

}
```

but i get error when i place it after on create : expected member declaration;

```
package app.helloworld.dashimir.com.diceroller

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    }
    val rollButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.roll_button)
    rollButton.text = "Let's Roll"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In kotlin (.kt) files your code should be inside a function (normally main). In Android development this means that usually your code will be inside methods like the `onCreate` from an activity, but other methods from classes or top level functions (outside of a class) work as well.

In your example the code you moved outside the `onCreate` includes a value declaration `val rollButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.roll_button)` which is valid inside the body of a class since it will be turned into a property of said class. But the second line: `rollButton.text = "Let's Roll"` is an assignment an those can only be performed inside a function.

Additionally, in Android with kotlin you have available [kotlin android extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) which let you reference views from the xml directly using their id without the need of using `findViewById`

Answer (score 0):

One of best ways it build out function.

**first:** add OnClick to button in xml file:

```
android:OnClick="OnClick"
```

**second:** build Onclick function in MainActivity class and don't forget the constructor (v:View):

```
package app.helloworld.dashimir.com.diceroller

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}


fun OnClick(v:View){
    val rollButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.roll_button)
    rollButton.text = "Let's Roll"
}
```